# Magento Search not working, redirecting to same page

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento search redirects to same page, how can I fix this issue

```
<?php
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();
?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo str_replace("https://","//",str_replace("http://","//",$this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl())) ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("catalogcategorysearch/general/enabled", $code)): ?>no-padding<?php endif; ?>">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
        <?php $categorySearchHelper = $this->helper('catalogcategorysearch'); ?>
        <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>" class="input-text" />
        <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("catalogcategorysearch/general/enabled", $code)): ?>
        <select id="<?php echo $categorySearchHelper->getCategoryParamName() ?>" name="<?php echo $categorySearchHelper->getCategoryParamName() ?>">
            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('All Categories') ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($this->getSearchableCategories() as $mainCategory): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $mainCategory->getEntityId()?>"><?php echo $mainCategory->getName() ?></option>
                <?php if ($categorySearchHelper->showSubCategories()) : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($this->getSearchableSubCategories($mainCategory) as $category) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $category->getEntityId()?>"><?php echo $categorySearchHelper->getIndentationText() . $category->getName()?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search'))  ?>" class="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Try advanced search in your magento store, if its working well try to copy those few codes into your default search location.
2. If you are using some pre designed templates, go to app->design->frontend->base->default->templates->catalogsearch->copy form.mini.phtml and result.phtml into your desired location (template location).
3. If you installed some search extensions, pls check whether it working or not.

Comment: how to try advance search?

Comment: http://your-store.com/catalogsearch/advanced/

Comment: more details follow this link http://inchoo.net/magento/advanced-search-in-magento-and-how-to-use-it-in-your-own-way/

Comment: advance search working but this is not. I have added the code above